# Is there a plugin for autocreating code from actions like in SPSS?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, taskmanager

I want to be able to change an edit I did 4 steps ago without having to redo all those 4 steps. Is this possible in a more accessible format than PyQGIS maybe through a plugin?